# Printing and exporting in Trello only works for boards, not lists

Tags: trello, printing

Why can I only print and export a board and a card but not a list?

Am I just missing something here? And is there a reason why exporting is only available as a JSON file?

Comment: The ability to print lists -- particularly the Done lists -- would be very useful for creating periodic reports to clients to highlight completed tasks on their projects/sites/systems. I'd be happy with a simple CSV output, which can be manipulated for presentation in Excel or Word or even email.

Answer (score 1):

Printing lists has not been a highly requested feature and would require a bit of work, whereas boards and cards are already well-formatted for printing. It's hard to prioritize them over features like copying cards.

JSON is the native data format for Trello, and thus is the easiest to implement. Other formats require munging and converting and will take some time, though the team plans to implement others formats in the future.

Comment: (Note: I work on the Trelo team.)

Comment: +1 for implementing this feature. I would be happy if I could just print the titles of each card in a list format.  That would be easy to do.

 We often want to see what cards we have in a particular list and either email it around, or print it out and discuss / cross things out. (Yes I know we could collaborate online but there are certain times when a hard copy is desired)

Answer (score -1):

This tool is useful for printing both boards and lists.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lpjpokeiblobbcpfheneagcfjlcjbkhf

Comment: What is that? The link doesn't give the name of the extension. Why would someone want to use that? Please elaborate.

Answer (score -1):

Before I found the Trello print feature on the Board menu, I simply copied and pasted into a Word doc. Yes, this is a bit tedious but it does allow me to set the formatting up to my preferences which are a bit cleaner than the Trello option. And, I was able to copy and paste checklist from the back of cards under each heading (again, to my prefs). These are options that it would be great for Trello to offer, but until then I'm glad I have a way to make it work.